# How do I display Flickr images in the Justified Gallery using JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I need to use Justified Gallery (http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/), but I don't know how to reference the pictures in the json data, I try to write some code, but can't display images, If my code is wrong, please help me give the correct code.

```
<body>
<div id="img"> </div>
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aishangbobozhu/photo/main/photo.json', function (photo) {
            $.each(photo, function (j) {
                $("#img").append(`<a href="'[j].url'" title="[j].name"> <img src='" + [j].url + "' /> </a>`)
                $('#img').justifiedGallery({
                        rowHeight: 120,
                        margins: 4,
                        randomize: true
                    })
                    .on('jg.complete', function () {
                        $(this).find('a').colorbox({
                            maxWidth: '80%',
                            maxHeight: '80%',
                            opacity: 0.8,
                            transition: 'elastic',
                            current: ''
                        });
                    });
            }); // close each()
        }); // close getJSON()

    });
</script>
```

My JSON format

```
{
"photo": [
{
    "url": "https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg",
    "name": "test1_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test2_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test3_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test4_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test5_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test6_1"
},
{
    "url": " https://s1.ax1x.com/2022/08/13/vY4zwQ.jpg ",
    "name": "test7_1"
}
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() 
{
    $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aishangbobozhu/photo/main/photo.json', function (data) 
    {
        $.each(data.photo, function (j,e) 
        {
            $("#img").append('<a href="'+ e.url + '" title="' + e.name +'"> <img src="' + e.url + '" /> </a>');
        });
    }).then(function()
    {
        $('#img').justifiedGallery({
            rowHeight: 120,
            margins: 4,
            randomize: true
        })
        .on('jg.complete', function () {
            $(this).find('a').colorbox({
                maxWidth: '80%',
                maxHeight: '80%',
                opacity: 0.8,
                transition: 'elastic',
                current: ''
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justifiedGallery/3.8.1/css/justifiedGallery.css" integrity="sha512-CRFv/YVJyElHXTiMgnhWKd2f04Hd/BUJkwcyqYmlpL1ugSYW23nNRazLk960mlz7dugTrETCGGjcsnspPOS6qA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="img"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justifiedGallery/3.8.1/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js" integrity="sha512-8dQZtymfQeDiZ4bBCFhrKZhDcZir15MqnEDBRiR6ReIVHLcdnCyJrhPIS0QifLGuMkFZsw9QMNeD9JtiLwieTQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js" integrity="sha512-DAVSi/Ovew9ZRpBgHs6hJ+EMdj1fVKE+csL7mdf9v7tMbzM1i4c/jAvHE8AhcKYazlFl7M8guWuO3lDNzIA48A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code runs without problems, solved my big problem, you are the best! Thank you sincerely!